# Ember unable to retain dropdown value

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-select

I am using Ember 2.5.0. In my application, I have created a page with a dropdown using the [ember-select-list](https://github.com/begedin/ember-select-list) plugin.

I am able to render the dropdown, but unable to retain the value of the dropdown. Whenever I select the value, I am getting the following exception in the chrome console:

> Assertion Failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object

Please find the following code, for reference:

**Template :**

```
{{select-list content=roles 
              optionValuePath="role"
              optionLabelPath="role" 
              value=role 
              action=(action (mut role))}}
```

**Route.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model(){
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
         books : this.store.findAll("book"),
         roles : this.store.findAll("role")
    });
},
setupController(controller,model){
   controller.set('users',model.books);
   controller.set('roles',model.roles);
 }
});
```

**Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    role:DS.attr()
});
```

In the router, when I pass `Array(roles: this.store.findAll("role").toArray())` instead of `model`, I can  retain the value, but it throws an error while passing model.

Anyone, could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ember-select-list documentation](https://github.com/begedin/ember-select-list#you-can-use-it-with-a-collection-of-simple-strings-or-complex-objects) and [unit test](https://github.com/begedin/ember-select-list/blob/master/tests/unit/components/select-list-test.js#L29) indicate that an `array` is required for the `content` property on the `{{select-list}}` helper.

This is why `Ember.RSVP.hash` seems to fail, as `hash` expects and returns an `object`, which is a type that ember-select-list is not configured to use.

Instead of `hash`, you should use `Ember.RSVP.all`, as `all` expects and returns an `array`, which should work.

I've created an [Ember Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/96a169613f6063893af4e485484ed2c9?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) to demonstrate.

If you'd rather not use ember-select-list, you might find it easier to merely use [Ember's `each` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each) to build out your own select list, like this:

```
<select onchange={{action "selectRole" value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each roles as |role| }}
    <option value="{{ role }}" label={{ role }}>
      {{ role }}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: But inside RSVP.hash I've 2Models one is book model and another one is Role I want only Role to be a array not book.Also is there any other easy way to build a select drop down I don't know why ember is so difficult for basic HTML form elements.

Comment: You can add `books` back in quite easily. I've updated the Twiddle example with comments. Also, I've updated the answer to include a native Ember approach to building out a `<select>` list using the `each` helper. The Twiddle example now includes this approach as well.

Comment: If using the latter approach, you could continue using `Ember.RSVP.hash`.

Comment: I like the ember-each helper approach since it doesn't need any plugin but how to retain the selected value in our book model. Could you please explain the selectRole action on how to retain the values? I'm new to ember I'm unsure how to get the selected value and put it in a model but definitely I'll give a try

Comment: I've tweaked the Twiddle to set the selected role on the books object. But, to `save` your model to your API, is a bigger question that requires an understanding of how Ember [updates and persists records](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_persisting-records).

Comment: I need your assistance again I am launching a page selected some option and i saved the object while re-opening the same page the option i selected earlier was selected by default how to avoid this?Why it retains or cached the selected value? Your help should be appreciable

Comment: StackOverflow in general, and comments, are not intended for ongoing, "forum-like" discussions. Please create [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that specifically asks your new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [ember-power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select) addon.

To your question, you can try this,

```
setupController(controller,model){
   controller.set('users',model.books);
   controller.set('roles',model.roles.toArray());
 }
```

let me know if this is not working

Comment: By adding that `then` it will no longer be a PromiseArray and it will not work.

Comment: Removed then part and simplified to just to array in setupcontroller